# Calling fread inside for loop fails

Tags: c

I have the following code (solely for benchmark purposes).

The code consists of creating a simple char array, dumping it to a file, and then reading it inside a `for` loop. 
How come that the read function fails due to failuer in `fopen` (`fread` returns `NULL`), but works if I comment out the `for` loop?

I am using Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1), and compiling simply with `clang -o rw rw.cpp`

```
int create(int, char**) {

    char a[256*256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256*256; i++)
        a[i] = char(i);

    // Dump to File
    FILE* f = fopen("file.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(a, 256*256*sizeof(char), 1, f);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}



int read(int, char**) {

    // IF this loop is commented out, the code works. Otherwise fails
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

        char a[256 * 256];

        FILE* f = fopen("file.bin", "rb");

        // Fails at this assertion
        assert(f);

        fread(a, 256*256*sizeof(char), 1, f);

        for (int k = 0; k < 256 * 256; k++) {
                if (a[k] != char(k)) {
                    printf("Bad Value %d %d\n", k, a[k]);
                }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us the error message.

Comment: @KeineLust sorry i made a mistake pasting the code. corrected now.

Comment: @CharlieMartin it fails at the assertion, `assert(f)`

Comment: There is only one file, you don't have to read it open it again and again in the loop. Move the `fopen` outside the `for` loop

Comment: If `char` is `signed` the you conversion of the large value (which will loop to a value much larger than fit in a `char`) is *implementation defined*.

Comment: `a[i] = char(i);` is a syntax error. Did you mean `a[i] = (char)i;`? Perhaps better is to define `unsigned char a[256*256]; ... a[i] = i;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never close the file opened inside the `for` loop in your read function. You're running out of filehandles, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `fopen` statement outside the `for` loop, since there is only one file. You don't need to open it inside the loop.